# Prove sequence $B[t]=\sum_{k=1}^{t}\sum_{i=1}^{k}S[i]$ for $S=\{0,1\}^T$ contains at most one element equal to $1$ at the same index as in $S$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, puzzle, sequence-of-function

I have the following problem. Given is a sequence of bits $S=\{0,1\}^T$ and functions

$$A[t]=\sum_{k=1}^{t}S[k]$$
$$B[t]=\sum_{k=1}^{t}A[k]$$

Now for sequence $\{B[0], B[1], \dots, B[T]\}$ I would like to prove the following.

1. It contains at most one element equal to $1$
2. That the first occurrence of element $1$ (if it exists) has the same index as the first occurrence of element $1$ in $S$.

**Thoughts**:

For proof $1$ I imagine one could split the problem into two cases. Case 1. If $S$ contains no $1$ then $B$ contains no $1$; And case 2. Either proof by contradiction and assume that for $t_1$ and $t_2>t_1$ that $B[t_1]=B[t_2]$ or prove that $B$ is always increasing $B[t+1]>B[t]$. I am however struggling to formally write down these ideas.

For the second statement perhaps one could also use proof by contradiction?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing the order of summation yields
$$B[t]
=\sum_{k=1}^t \sum_{i=1}^k S[i]
=\sum_{i=1}^t \sum_{k=i}^t S[i]
=\sum_{i=1}^t S[i] \sum_{k=i}^t 1
=\sum_{i=1}^t S[i] (t-i+1),
$$
so
\begin{align}
B[t+1]
&=\sum_{i=1}^{t+1} S[i] (t+1-i+1) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^t S[i] (t+1-i+1) + S[t+1] \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^t S[i] (t-i+1) + \sum_{i=1}^t S[i] + S[t+1] \\
&= B[t] + \sum_{i=1}^{t+1} S[i] \\
&> B[t] \quad\text{if $\sum_{i=1}^{t+1} S[i] > 0$} \\
\end{align}
Also, if $S[1]=S[2]=\dots=S[\bar{t}-1]=0$ and $S[\bar{t}]=1$, then
$$B[t]=\sum_{i=1}^t 0 (t-i+1) = 0 \quad \text{for $t < \bar{t}$}$$ and
$$B[\bar{t}]=\sum_{i=1}^\bar{t} S[i] (\bar{t}-i+1) = S[\bar{t}] (\bar{t}-\bar{t}+1) = 1.$$